# Were the NX-01 or any other major elements of Enterprise referenced in an earlier series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

With the obvious exception (for the most part) of the 2012 film, Star Trek movies and TV series generally stay pretty true to canon in terms of in-universe history.  So I began to wonder, as I'm now watching through the Enterprise series, if any of the people, places, or things from the prequel series were ever talked about in earlier works?

Was there ever mention of Jonathan Archer, the NX-01, a Temporal Cold War, or any other foundational elements of the Enterprise series before that series was produced?  Or were all these pieces covered solely within the Enterprise timeline?

NOTE:  I'm not looking for any crossover episodes where Enterprise just happens to cover some well-known element of Star Trek universe history.  I'm looking for anything to show that the Star Trek universe had historical information about core series components like the NX-01, Jonathan Archer, et. al. *before* Enterprise was created - something that shows, for example, that "Jonathan Archer" wasn't just pulled from a hat when the creators were looking to name the captain of Starfleet's first Enterprise.

Comment: The final episode of Enterprise was basically a TNG episode, so it *could* be said to be referencing Enterprise in The Next Generation.

Comment: @Xantec Interesting to know, but (without actually having seen the Enterprise episode you're referring to just yet) I'm fairly confident that does not fit the parameters of my query - see the final paragraph.

Comment: RE: Jonathan Archer,  it seems that the name was near enough [pulled from a hat](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Jonathan_Archer#Background_information)

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered at all. Anything that pre-dates the series would fall into your "covers well-known elements" category, wouldn't it?

Comment: @bitmask I think you're a bit confused as to what I'm looking for.  For example, Dr. Phlox's involvement with the virus that made the Klingons temporarily smooth-headed would *not* be something I'm looking for.  However, someone from a TNG-era series having mentioned reading about a Starfleet tactical officer named "Malcolm Reed" in the history books would be in-scope.

Comment: @Iszi: So you are explicitly looking for someone mentioning a *name* from ENT?

Comment: @bitmask I suppose at this point that is the only thing I can think of that would fit, though I'd be happy to be shown an example of the Temporal Cold War being mentioned in TOS or something.  I'd like to see something that shows the NX-01 and her crew and overall mission were actually built from pre-established Star Trek universe history - not just one or two episodes that they threw in as a shout-out to the series predecessors.

Comment: @Iszi My current answer has a name, but I do have more I can add.  However, they _are_ just one/two episodes, and a filled in backstory - not large arcs, or objects like the ship itself.  If you are still interested, I shall try edit it in later when I have time to make it more complete.

Answer (score 8):

This is so obscure that I cannot recall the episode, but I did a double-take when I heard it:

Captain Picard had an upcoming meeting with the Xindi ambassador.  I don't think there was any additional information.

It seems that at some point during/just before TNG, the Xindi solved their problems (See: All of ENT Season 3) and were now opening up relations with Starfleet and the Federation.

While I believe I later found out it was spelled "Xendi" in the script, Picard's pronunciation was near-identical to the Xindi of the Enterprise series.

Comment: Wasn't that the Kzinti ambassador?

Comment: @Junuxx The script spelled it "Xendi", IIRC, so no.  Though I think the Kzinti were in an episode of TAS..

Comment: There were the [Xendi Sabu](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xendi_Sabu_system) and [Xendi Kabu](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xendi_Kabu_system) star systems featured in TNG, so it is possible that Xendi and Xindi are separate races.

Answer (score 7):

NX-01 never appeared in any other series before it. While the 2009 reboot movie and *Star Trek Beyond* later referenced Enterprise-era events, before the series "Star Trek: Enterprise" the NX-01 did not exist.

Comment: That the "Admiral Archer" that Scotty mentions is Jonathan Archer of NX-01 fame is not canon. In particular, he would have had to re-joined Starfleet after being Commander-in-Chief, retiring, and being elected Federation President. Also, he would have been 145 at the time the movie took place.

Comment: @Plutor McCoy was 137 years old in the first episode of TNG, so it's not overly far-fetched that Captain Archer was still alive...

Comment: It could have much more easily been his grandson.

Comment: Still, the reference to a beagle means it was highly probably intended to be a nod to Enterprise.

Comment: The dog must have been over 100 years too though... It's a nod to Enterprise, but realisticly it's probably Jonathan Archers Grandson (or daughter?) and a different dog.

Comment: He could have gotten another dog...

Answer (score 5):

There's an episode of *Voyager* ("Hope and Fear") where they use the NX-01A marking for the USS Dauntless. There's no other mention of this designation being used for other ships. Other than this, the NX-01 designation has never been referenced in any of the previous shows. There are references to "Archer" in various forms (planet names, ships, etc). But no mention of Jonathan Archer or any of the events that took place in the *Enterprise* series.

Comment: ...and considering "A" is usually used only for ships with the same name as their predecessor (e.g. *Enterprise*), this feels like conclusive evidence that the "original" NX-01 did not exist in canon by this point.

Answer (score 4):

If you watch TNG's *Yesterday's Enterprise* episode, they are heading to Archer-4.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. It should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not directly reference any events of Enterprise (NX-01, Johnathan Archer, et al), in the TNG episode [New Ground](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/New_Ground_%28episode%29) Geordi references  Zefram Cochrane engaging the first warp drive. This ties in to First Contact and thus references events prior to Enterprise. If I remember correctly there is even a (recorded?) speech by Zefram Cochrane in one of the earlier episodes of Enterprise.

Comment: Zefram Cochrane existed in Star Trek canon even before TNG.  Check out the Memory Alpha page for his TOS appearance.  This is another example of an ENT episode that just happens to have a bit of established ST history in it.  I'm looking for tie-ins to *core series components* like the NX-01 Enterprise, Archer, T'Pol, Phlox, Hoshi, et. al.

Answer (score 2):

There are several references retconned into the events of Enterprise from TNG and the films, notably the appearance of the planet '[Archer IV](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Archer_IV)', originally mentioned in the TNG episode "Yesterday's Enterprise" as the site of a site of a "radiation anomaly" that turned out to be a temporal rift. The planet is also seen in the background of the ['Stellar Cartography'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz3CYcjdSaI) sequence in "Star Trek : Generations"

The planet forms the backdrop in Enterprise episodes "Strange New World" and "Home" as the first planet chosen by Captain Jonathan Archer for a survey mission.

[image]

We also see a USS Archer mentioned in the film 'Star Trek : Nemesis'
[image]

Additionally, a major arc of the 4th Season of Enterprise (notably episodes "Affliction" and "Divergence") dealt with retconning the differing appearance of Klingons in TNG from their appearance in TOS (lampshaded and then averted by Worf in DS9 "Trouble with Tribbles" who simply says

> "We do not discuss it with outsiders"

by having them take 'augmented' DNA from humans and combine it with their own in an attempt to enhance themselves. The end result was a mutation of a highly-contagious virus that caused massive changes in physical appearance. Phlox comments that

> PHLOX: In the future, it may be possible to reverse the cosmetic
>   effects.

Comment: These aren't really references to *Enterprise*, it's just things that *Enterprise* picked up and used to build upon.  You're putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: I'm happy to admit that these are retcons. The unanswered question is whether those things were deliberately chosen as "trapdoors" (e.g. potential plotpoints mentioned but not built on in order to leave space for future writing) or whether they were simply plucked at random from older episodes.

Comment: Interesting note: "Archer IV" implies that the primary star in the planet's system is actually what is named for Captain Archer - not the planet itself, which would be the fourth planet by orbital altitude from that star.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan Archer, NX-01 and the Temporal cold war are all products of the Enterprise series, and not previously referenced on any earlier made Star Trek Television series. It is worth noting however, that other elements of Enterprise are based on earlier series / stories. Mentions of Zephrim Cochrane, the Andorians, the War with the Romulans (which according to cannon was fought with nuclear weapons, though that seems not to be the case in Enterprise) et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason there was never any mention of the NX-01 USS Enterprise prior to the television series was due to a slight change in the timeline after the events in Star Trek First Contact.
Prior to that point in time there was no mention of the NX-01 Enterprise or it would have appeared among the models displayed in the briefing rooms of the Enterprise's D & E.

When the Enterprise E traveled back to 2063 in pursuit of the Borg, Data states "the temporal wake appears to be protecting them from the changes in the timeline".
It is feasible to assume that before they Enterprise E traveled back to 2063 history would recognise the NX-01 under a different name & thus not included in he list of ships to bare the name Enterprise.

Only when Diana Troi informs Zefram Cochran "that's our ship, the Enterprise" does the name Enterprise linger in Cochran's mind over the years & influences the name of the NX-01 to be so named in favour of the slightly alternate timeline prior to Star Trek First Contact.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. This just says *why* something *wasn't* mentioned as opposed to **were any of these things mentioned**. Not voting to close or downvoting, but suggesting this is more like a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The aircraft carrier USS Enterprise that was seen in the movie Star Trek IV - The Voyage Home is present in the Enterprise D briefing room, that is not a federation ship. Also the NX-01 is not present, only the original Constitustion class, the Enterprise B Excelsior class, Enterprice C Ambasador class & the Enterprise D Galaxy class. No crude NX-01 Enterprise is visible I'm afraid.

Comment: In the George Lucas Special Edition Blu-Ray there is a glaringly out of place digital model of the NX-01 inserted into all the conference room scenes

Answer (score 0):

Starting with  *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* there were displays of various previous *Enterprises*, starting with some of the many sailing vessels named *Enterprise*, located on Federation Starfleet vessels named *Enterprise*.  Naturally the later shows and movies had more Federation Starfleet vessels named *Enterprise* to include in the displays, and they also varied on which ocean ships named *Enterprise* they included.

Here is a link to a discussion at the *Ex Astris Scientia* website.

http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/ship_walls.htm[1](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/ship_walls.htm)

Naturally the *Enterprise* NX-01 is not in any of them.  But since none of them are all inclusive of space vessels named *Enterprise* it is quite possible that  it was left out because it was Earth Starfleet instead of Federation Starfleet and/or was not as distinctive in appearance as other sea and space vessels.

So no it has not been seen or mentioned but the absence of evidence is not necessarily evidence of absence.

Answer (score -1):

The NX 01 does not appear in any of the conference room models, the loop is that it is technically NOT a federation vessel since the federation is yet to be created.  It is however a Starfleet vessel.

Answer (score -7):

The Enterprise D and E have gold models of NX-01 in the meeting room! Its there! Very crude in D but fits the form,  Enterprise E is an exact

Comment: Could you provide a photo? Or an episode number where it's visible?

Comment: This is... not possible.

Comment: As far as the models in the various conference rooms of the ships check out this link: http://www.startrek.com/article/guest-blog-the-lineage-of-ships-that-bear-the-name-enterprise. I do not see any uses of NX-01 models according to this.